# Understanding JSON-RPC in Perl

Tags: html, json, perl, rpc, json-rpc

I am trying to understand the concept of JSON RPC and it's Perl implementation. Though I can fin d a lot of examples for Python/Java, I find surprisingly little or no examples for it in Perl.

I am following [this example](http://blog.wlindley.com/2013/05/an-example-json-endpoint-in-perl/) but am not sure it is complete. The example I had in mind was to add 2 integers. Now I have a very basic HTML page set up, like so:

```
<html>
<body>
    <input type="text" name="num1"><br>
    <input type="text" name="num2"><br>
    <button>Add</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Next, based on the example above, I have 3 files:

**test1.pl**

```
# Daemon version
use JSON::RPC::Server::Daemon;

# see documentation at:
# https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/JSON-RPC/lib/JSON/RPC/Legacy.pm

my $server = JSON::RPC::Server::Daemon->new(LocalPort => 8080);
$server -> dispatch({'/test' => 'myApp'});
$server -> handle();
```

**test2.pl**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use JSON::RPC::Client;

my $client = new JSON::RPC::Client;

my $uri = 'http://localhost:8080/test';
my $obj = {
method => 'sum', # or 'MyApp.sum'
params => [10, 20],
};

my $res = $client->call( $uri, $obj );

if($res){
if ($res->is_error) {
print "Error : ", $res->error_message;
} else {
print $res->result;
}
} else {
print $client->status_line;
}
```

**myApp.pl**

```
package myApp;

#optionally, you can also
use base qw(JSON::RPC::Procedure);  # for :Public and :Private attributes

sub sum : Public(a:num, b:num) {
my ($s, $obj) = @_;
return $obj->{a} + $obj->{b};
}

1;
```

While I understand what these files individually do, I am at a complete loss when it comes to combining them and making them work together.

My questions are as follows:

- Does the button in the HTML page come inside a  tag (like we would normally do in a CGI-based program)? If yes, what file does that call? If no, then how do I pass the values to be added?
- What is the order of execution of the 3 Perl files? Which one calls which one? How is the flow of execution?
- When I tried to run the perl files from the CLI, i.e using $./test2.pl, I got the following error: Error 301 Moved Permanently. What moved permanently? which file was it trying to access? I tried running the files from withing `/var/www/html` and `/var/www/html/test`.

Some help in understanding the nuances of this would really be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *Does the button in the HTML page come inside a tag (like we would*
>   *normally do in a CGI-based program)? If yes, what file does that call?*
>   *If no, then how do I pass the values to be added?*

HTML has nothing at all to do with JSON-RPC. While the RPC call is done via an HTTP POST request, if you're doing that from the browser, you'll need to use XMLHttpRequest (i.e: AJAX). Unlink an HTML form post the `Content-encoding:` header will need to be something specific to JSON-RPC (e.g: application/json or similar), and you'll need to encode your form data via `JSON.stringify` and correctly construct the JSON-RPC "envelope", including the `id`, `jsonrpc`, `method` and `params` properties.

Rather than doing this by hand you might use a purpose-build JSON-RPC JavaScript client like the [jQuery-JSONRP](https://github.com/datagraph/jquery-jsonrpc/) plugin (there are many others) -- although the protocol is so simple that implementations usually are less than 20 lines of code.

From the jQuery-RPC documentation, you'd set up the connection like this:

```
$.jsonRPC.setup({
  endPoint: '/ENDPOINT-ROUTE-GOES-HERE'
});
```

and you'd call the server-side method like this:

```
$.jsonRPC.request('sum', {
  params: [YOURNUMBERINPUTELEMENT1.value, YOURNUMBERINPUT2.value],
  success: function(result) {
    /* Do something with the result here */
  },
  error: function(result) {
    /* Result is an RPC 2.0 compatible response object */
  }
});
```

> *What is the order of execution of the 3 Perl files? Which one calls*
>   *which one? How is the flow of execution?*

You'll likely only need `test2.pl` for testing. It's an example implementation of a JSON-RPC client. You likely want your client to run in your web-browser (as described above). The client JavaScript will make an HTTP POST request to wherever `test1.pl` is serving content. (e.g: `http://localhost:8080`).

Or, if you want to keep your code as HTML<-->CGI, then you'll need to make JSON-RPC client calls from within your Perl CGI server-side code (which seems silly if it's on the same machine).

When `test1.pl` calls `dispatch`, the `MyApp` module will be loaded.
Then, when `test1.pl` calls `handle`, the `sum` function in the `MyApp` package will be called.

The `JSON::RPC::Server` module takes care of marshalling from JSON-RPC to perl datastructures and back again around the call to `handle`. `die()`ing in `sum` should result in a JSON-RPC exception being transmitted to the calling client, rather than death of the `test1.pl` script.

> *When I tried to run the perl files from the CLI, i.e using*
>   *$./test2.pl, I got the following error: Error 301 Moved Permanently.*
>   *What moved permanently? which file was it trying to access? I tried*
>   *running the files from withing /var/www/html and /var/www/html/test.*

This largely depends the configuration of your machine. There's nothing obvious (in your code) to suggest that a `301 Moved Permanently` would be issued in response to a valid JSON-RPC request.