# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'setup' of undefined in jquery jsonrpc client

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, json-rpc

I need to call a invoke a remote rpc procedure via jquery. I user jquery-json plugin for this purpose. >>https://github.com/datagraph/jquery-jsonrpc/

```
<input style='width:100px;float:left;margin:20px 10px 0px 10px;' type="button" id="JsonHangup"  class="btn btn-primary" value="HangUp"   />




    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.json-1.3.min.js"></script>
<script> src="js/jquery-jsonrpc-master/jquery.jsonrpc.js"</script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#JsonHangup").click(function(){
   alert("The paragraph was clicked.");

$.jsonRPC.setup({
  endPoint: 'https://172.31.0.164:42338/jsonrpc/API/hangup'
});
$.jsonRPC.request('test', {
  params: ["hoi"],
  success: function(result) {
    /* Do something with the result here */
  },
  error: function(result) {
    /* Result is an RPC 2.0 compatible response object */
  }
});


});
});
</script>
```

It gives following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'setup' of undefined
```

Can anyone help me on this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You need:

```
<script src="js/jquery-jsonrpc-master/jquery.jsonrpc.js"></script>
```

instead of:

```
<script> src="js/jquery-jsonrpc-master/jquery.jsonrpc.js"</script>
```

You're closing the `script` tag at the wrong place which make the browser cannot load the file properly. It should be closed after your `src` attribute, not before.

Comment: Thanks. Now it show a diffrent error: "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined ". Please refer: http://pastebin.com/kwnBEwTU

Comment: Please check `js/jquery.min.js` is the correct file path or not. Seem like you cannot load `jQuery` properly here

Comment: They are indeed at the right location. Is there any particular version of Jquery I sould use. I even put jquery-1.11.0.min.js instead. But still no luck.

Comment: Try to use direct link instead `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: I used direct link. It eliminates "$ is not defined" error but old error reappears: " Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'setup' of undefined agent.htm:124
(anonymous function) agent.htm:124
jQuery.event.dispatch jquery.js:3242
elemData.handle.eventHandle"

Comment: Did you close the `<script>` properly like my provided answer?

Comment: When I close script tag for direct link like <script> src="" </script> it gives me error `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined `. When I use the exact line you given in last line that error is gone. But when I click on Button following error is shown: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'setup' of undefined agent.htm:124
(anonymous function) agent.htm:124
jQuery.event.dispatch jquery.js:3242
elemData.handle.eventHandle`

Comment: No, you need to use `<script src="" </script>`, not `<script> src="" </script>`

Comment: Thanks. I am doing it that way. This is how it looks now. `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.json-1.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-jsonrpc-master/jquery.jsonrpc.js"></script>
`. I am following [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21204713/understanding-json-rpc-in-perl in which a JSON rpc client example is given. It seems that error occurs at line `$.jsonRPC.setup`. : `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'setup' of undefined agent.htm:124
...`

Comment: Looping @David-SkyMesh